# Highcharts rounding yaxis and xaxis digits

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to round yaxis and xaxis down. For example 3843 should be 3.843 on the graph and tooltip show 3.843 k.

I have got the tooltip working but cant get it to change the graphs yaxis and xaxis value so that the graph can show all sides fully.

As you can see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kzL0phfu/

This is what xaxis looks like

```
yAxis: {
gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
lineWidth: 0,
min: 0,
gridLineColor: "#808080",
gridLineDashStyle: "Solid",
gridLineWidth: 2,
labels: {
  format: '{value:.2f}',
  style: {
    color: '#c4c4c4',
    font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataLabels` `formatter` to achieve desired result

```
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      dataLabels: {
        useHTML: true,
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          value = this.y;
          numericSymbolDetector = Math.abs(this.y);
          if (numericSymbolDetector > 1000) {
            value = Highcharts.numberFormat(value / 1000, 3, '.', '') ;
          }
          return value
        },
        style: {
          color: '#c4c4c4',
          font: '5px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
      },
      //enableMouseTracking: false
    },
    series: {
      lineColor: '#808080'
    }
  },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z10a3r9L/1/) demonstration

Comment: Hello, yes but the only problem is with this the the chart is not equal as 3.84 still shows bigger then 7 because 3.84 is 3840 but what I am after is making it so its able to show the graph equally so that the entire graph shows instead of the line due to it being to big of a number. As you can see 6.245 is still over the 5000 mark on the graph it should be over the 5 mark only but with the k on the end.

Comment: Still not getting what you want. Can you add some screenshot which shows exactly what you want.

Comment: What I am trying to do is make it so when its 3000 it will round down to 3k but also on graph shows as 3 instead of 3000. As currently the tool tip rounds to 3k and the label on the graph, but the graph its self does not round down to 3. As currently as you can see you can not see other parts of the graph due to the size of the number.

Comment: Any ideas ? As i have tried all day today and cant find anything

Comment: as you mention _3000 it will round down to 3k_ which is ok but how( _but the graph its self does not round down to 3. As currently as you can see you can not see other parts of the graph due to the size of the number_ ) this is possible. How can you compare four digit number with two digit number??. Graph is correct. If I am not understanding you. Please add screenshot

Comment: What I am after is rounding it down on the graph only. Meaning that on the graph it would show as 3 but on tool tip it would show as 3k. Here is a example

https://gyazo.com/f3bec46f19dfd64cc328f8a280eb0e18

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z10a3r9L/2/  check this. But K in tooltip is not working as values are changed. Finding a way out of K

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/qvtnqs8r/ .This is last **hack** I can do

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display yAxis labels the same way, get rid of the formatter from the yAxis.labels object (then the thousand prefix will display). In case you want to display exact values of the points as yAxis labels, you can update `tickPositions` array on load event and format them adequately. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ojno8rx1/

Comment: Hello, yes but the only problem is with this the the chart is not equal as 3.84 still shows bigger then 7 because 3.84 is 3840 but what I am after is making it so its able to show the graph equally so that the entire graph shows instead of the line due to it being to big of a number.